# Keras confusion about number of layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I'm a bit confused about the number of layers that are used in Keras models. The documentation is rather opaque on the matter.

According to Jason Brownlee the first layer technically consists of two layers, the input layer, specified by `input_dim` and a hidden layer. See the first questions on [his blog](http://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/).

In all of the Keras documentation the first layer is generally specified as
`model.add(Dense(number_of_neurons, input_dim=number_of_cols_in_input, activtion=some_activation_function))`.

The most basic model we could make would therefore be:

```
 model = Sequential()
 model.add(Dense(1, input_dim = 100, activation = None))
```

Does this model consist of a single layer, where 100 dimensional input is passed through a single input neuron, or does it consist of two layers, first a 100 dimensional input layer and second a 1 dimensional hidden layer?

Further, if I were to specify a model like this, how many layers does it have?

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim = 100, activation = 'sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1)))
```

Is this a model with 1 input layer, 1 hidden layer, and 1 output layer or is this a model with 1 input layer and 1 output layer?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your first one consists of a 100 neurons input layer connected to one single output neuron

Your second one consists of a 100 neurons input layer, one hidden layer of 32 neurons and one output layer of one single neuron.

You have to think of your first layer as your input layer (with the same number of neurons as the dimenson, so 100 for you) connected to another layer with as many neuron as you specify (1 in your first case, 32 in the second one)

In Keras what is useful is the command

```
model.summary()
```

Comment: beat me to suggesting `model.summary` ;) it's a lifesaver and I'd highly recommend it to OP.

Comment: As here we see one hidden layer. Is it possible to add multiple hidden layer?

Comment: @Advika I'd be blasted if you still haven't gotten an answer but for posterity's sake: `model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'sigmoid'))` would add a hidden layer of 32 neurons with sigmoid activation given that you are using `model = Sequential()`. 
Another way to add layers is through the [keras functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/)

Comment: Hi. For a binary classification problem with shape `(129880, 33)` what would you recommend? Maybe `model.add(Dense(50, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],), activation='relu', input_dim=32))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')) `? `input_dim=32` represents columns/features right? `50` correspond to a hidden layer with 50 neurons right? How to choose that?

Answer (score 13):

For your first question, the model is :

1 input layer and 1 output layer.

For the second question :

1 input layer

1 hidden layer

1 activation layer (The sigmoid one)

1 output layer

For the input layer, this is abstracted by Keras with the input_dim arg or input_shape, but you can find this layer in :

```
from keras.layers import Input
```

Same for the activation layer.

```
from keras.layers import Activation
```

Comment: Based on the other answer I'm not totally sure you're right about the first model. I think it is just one input layer and a single output layer without any hidden layers. I think you're correct about the second model though.

Comment: Hi, indeed, I wrote it too quick.
It's composed of 1 input layer (100 neurons) and one output layer. (Composed of 1 neuron)
I'm going to edit it

Comment: Thanks for clarifying

Comment: By activation layer, do you mean activation function?

Comment: What is an 'Activation Layer'?

Comment: I think similar to first case, for the second case it'll be three layers, one input, one hidden and one output. @Pusheen_the_dev don't you think so?

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create a `Sequential` model and add a Dense layer as the first layer.
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.Input(shape=(16,)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
# Now the model will take as input arrays of shape (None, 16)
# and output arrays of shape (None, 32).
# Note that after the first layer, you don't need to specify
# the size of the input anymore:
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(32))
model.output_shape
```

**(None, 32)**

```
model.layers
```

**[<keras.layers.core.dense.Dense at 0x7f494062e950>,
<keras.layers.core.dense.Dense at 0x7f4944048d90>]**

```
model.summary()
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDfbn.png)

it may help you understand clearly

Comment: Could you copy the text directly instead of an image ?