# Confusion about Hidden Layers in LSTMs/GRUs in Keras

Tags: python, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm aware of questions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45328843/keras-confusion-about-number-of-layers) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394026/keras-clarification-on-definition-of-hidden-layer), but they cannot clarify the following for me.

Given some random LSTM-Model like this:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu')) # Input and Hidden 1
model.add(LSTM(8)) # Hidden 2
model.add(LSTM(8)) # Hidden 3
model.add(Dense(1)) # Output
```

Reading about a setup like this, for exmaple on SO, it is often said that we have a network with an input-layer, three hidden-layers and an output-layer.

Anyhow, what I am confused about: Isn't this setup a stacking of three LSTMs leading to a *deep-LSTM* rather than three hidden-layers?
This means any of these three LSTMs should have the option to set a variable kind of hidden layers within itself (obviously in Keras it has not).

Is Keras just calling these layers *LSTMs* for convenience or am I misunderstanding the concept of LSTM-stacking? Or is a LSTM-cell just a form of a hidden-layer?